# Twig two loops in one

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to do two loops in one time but I don't know why.
Here is my code :

the controller:

```
foreach($query_object as $query) {
                 $result[] = $query->getQuery();
                 $result_query[] = $query->getId();
            }
    }   
            if (isset($result)) 
        {


            return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Profile:show.html.twig', array(
                'user' => $user, 'result' => $result, 'result_query' => $result_query
            ));
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Profile:show.html.twig', array(
                'user' => $user
            ));
        }
    }
```

And the view :

```
{% if  result is defined %}
                    {% for query in result %} 
                        {% for query2 in result_query %}                        
                            <li><a href="{{ path('biblishare_biblio', { 'queryId' : query2 , 'title' : query }) }}" title="{{ query }}" class="a">{{ query }}</a></li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
```

The problem is that now I have the results twice...
How can I resolve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know what exactly your problem is but you can shorten and simplify your code by using array keys for your query-id like:

```
foreach($query_object as $query) {
  $result[$query->getId()] = $query->getQuery();
}
```

and in twig you do

```
{% for id,query in result %}                        
    <li><a href="{{ path('biblishare_biblio', { 'queryId' : id , 'title' : query }) }}" title="{{ query }}" class="a">{{ query }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It is better, I don't have all the repetitions of the results by the number of iterations in the loop. But the queryId is not right, if I have 3 results the queryId is 0, 1, 2

Comment: you should inspect $query_object